# Text View navegable Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, activity, textview

Como puedo hacer para que al darle **`click`** a un texto me lleve a otra Activity con datos que después mostraré en la siguiente Anctivity

**XML**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código**

```
public class iniciarSesion extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView ISETregistrar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_iniciar_sesion);

        ISETregistrar=findViewById(R.id.sesionETregistrar);

        ISETregistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(iniciarSesion.this, registrarse.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

**Diseño**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual es el error que tienes ?

Comment: Al parecer ya tienes el código para abrir la actividad. Cuál es el problema?